# How to display Today's Date as a column in Dynamics FetchXML result?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

How to display Today's Date as a column in Dynamics FetchXML result. I am writing a tool to create pivot tables from the results. I have a requirement where I have to display today's date as a whole column.

Is it possible?

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do something like this, it's not possible in fetchxml: (`getdate()` results the current datetime stamp in SQL)

```
SELECT name, createdon AS created_date, getdate()
FROM account
```

Probably you have to get the dataset/datatable using fetchxml & add a dynamic column on your side before binding it to grid control or something else.